# Python Azure BlobTrigger how to get metadata

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm creating a new function app for a blob event trigger by using the command `func new --template BlobTrigger`. The generated Python entrypoint for the BlobTrigger looks as follows:

```
def main(myblob: func.InputStream):
    logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob \n"
                 f"Name: {myblob.name}\n"
                 f"Blob Size: {myblob.length} bytes")
```

The myblob contains the image blob data that was uploaded to the blob storage. I'd need the corresponding metadata to this blob as well. I haven't found any way to get the metadata from the `myblob` parameter, looking at the available functions and attributes, it doesn't have any to retrieve the metadata from it.

Is there a way to get the metadata from this object or would I have to do a separate call to the Blob storage to retrieve that info?

Comment: I know it is not really related but you should use eventgrid rather than blob trigger: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-event-overview

Comment: I can't see anywhere that the event grid sends the actual blob or the metadata?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you getting an idea of [event-based triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-event-trigger) in Azure Data Factory to implement your requirements. You could configure the blob account:

[image]

When an event trigger fires for a specific blob, you could captures the folder path and file name of the blob into the properties `@triggerBody().folderPath` and `@triggerBody().fileName`.

Comment: My trigger is event based, it's a `BlobTrigger` created as a function app which works fine. I just don't know how to access the metadata from the posted callback function

Comment: `BlobTrigger` are not event based.It is a pull mode. If you look at the documentatation, the first purple note explain this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob